# Python script works. when i try to run it after creating an exe. it gives me "cannot find path" error and passes escape character

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've created a simple python script in windows to select random songs from a specific folder network drive in this case. When I run it. works great. after I created the 'exe' file with pyinstaller. the "escape" \ character get pass therefore. it says "cannot find specific Path Z:\ .I've tried Z:/ and Z: same issue. script works fine. any ideas?
thanks in advance.

```
    randomfile = random.choice(os.listdir("Z:\\"))
    file = 'Z:\\' + randomfile
```

Comment: This code defines a filename, but doesn't _do_ anything with it; obviously the error happens later on in the code.  Edit the question to include the code that tries to access the file, and also the full error traceback message.

Comment: The above code seems fine if the file exists, for better help do what @JohnGordon said.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work, it had to do something with which account was being run in. thanks